# How can I find the variance using a for loop and two lists and defining the function?

Tags: python, list, variance

I need to write a function called var_fun that returns the variance of the list and testing with 2 lists. I have to return the standard deviation of each element actually.
list_1 = [8, 8, 3, 5, 5, 8, 1, 4, 8, 6, 3, 10, 9]
list_2 = [8, 12, 3, 5, 5, 8, 1, 4, 8, 3, 10, 9]

This is the code that I did but it returns <function var_func at 0x7f462679ad08>
How can I solve this?

```
def var_fun(x):
  for i in x:
    var = ((i - mean_fun(x))**2)
  return var_fun
print(var_fun(list_1))
print(var_fun(list_2))
```

This is my mean_fun:

```
def mean_fun(values) :
  length = len(values)
  total_sum = 0
  for i in range(length):
    total_sum += values[i]
    average = (total_sum/length)
  return round(average, 2)
print(mean_fun(list_1))
print(mean_fun(list_2))
```

The output should look like this:
[25.0, 9.0, 9.0, 4.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 9.0, 16.0]
[28.41, 11.09, 11.09, 5.43, 1.77, 1.77, 2.79, 2.79, 2.79, 7.13, 13.47, 32.15]

Comment: Does the answer posted below solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

In function `var_fun()`, return `var` instead of `var_fun`. That should solve the problem.

You get the error because you are trying to return the function itself.

Also, these lines don't make any sense. You can remove them:

```
mean_fun = list_1
mean_fun = list_2
```

## Better Alternative:

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.var.html
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html

Have a look at the above numpy functions which does the job of directly calculating the mean and variance.